# IPFS for media files

Tags: nft, ipfs

I'm trying to build an nftmarketplace that takes in an audio file, can I use IPFS for storing my URi, was wondering if the file would be too large as all the tutorials I've worked with mainly used Images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you definitely can use ipfs. there is no limitations on type of file.
you should decide on that case that you want to involve backend into your system or not. is that centralized or decentralized?

if everything must be handled on frontend side, the uploading process on ipfs takes much more time for large media and do it sync on browser tab of user. you can use some platform such as **pinata** , **nft.storage**, **moralis sdk**, ... and other similar platforms instead of fully boot up an IPFS server or maintaining this particular server. (search for pin feature in ipfs)

if you decide to handle some parts on backend, it will be handled all above operation on backend and also async. it means the user will upload the file on backend and then backend take care of uploading the file to ipfs.

another usages of backend is that we have a problem to getting the file from ipfs is that it take more time rather than retrieving data from CDN like Aws S3.
you actually store the file on multiple places.

**plz vote it up if it is useful :)**

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you unfortunately I cant upvote yet

Answer (score 0):

IPFS is not good for large files. I did some research and found that supducks was a few MB and that was the biggest I saw among many projects. Even 10mb could be considered a large file. I have not checked Arweave but want to.

Comment: Hey, thaank you that was incredibly helpful, was wondering if I could dm you as I shave some questions

Comment: Please upvote and feel free to DM.